# AppFabric, when to cache: HTTP POST vs HTTP GET?

Tags: http, caching, appfabric

I'm testing a web application that uses AppFabric.

The application creates a cache item when it receives a HTTP POST to create a new data entry.

If I then restart the cache cluster and retrieve the same data entry using a HTTP GET, the application is not creating the cache item.

Do you agree with this behavior or should HTTP GETs also create cache items?

This is not a programming question and I'm not a developer, but I think this is the most adequate StackExchange community for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to one of the developers, it's indeed a bug. The HTTP GETs should definitely put items in the cache.